# Why is my API requset returning only a string payload [JavaScript]

Tags: json, api, axios

I am new to working with API and I am working on a web-extension to fetch a random quote.

Each time I refresh the page the output works fine with `response.data` however, I would like to use each object from the responses... and not have the entire data on the page so I can add my custom styles.

I am using Axios + pure js

and I would like to access these values[image]

Can someone please tell me, what I am doing wrong here?
For now, all I can access is request.data

```
axios
.get(url)
.then(function (response) {
  showTextToUser(response.data);
  //NOT WORKING console.log(response['verse']);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Here's my request using axios [image]

Answer (score 2):

This is how axios response object look like

```
{
  config:{},
  data:{ --PAYLOAD YOU SENT FROM SERVER --},
  headers:{},
  request:{},
  status: // status code,
  statusText:''

}
```

I think you will find the `verse` object in data object as `response.data.verse`

Comment: I already tried to log the response.data.verse but received undefined instead

Comment: Would be better If you could show the code which is responsible for handling the request.